# Product Name not displaying properly in Bundle Identifier - numbers not showing?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-developer-program, bundle-identifier

On my app developer site I created a an app ID of org.myorg.54Miles  My apps name is 54Miles.

In XCode my product name is set to 54Miles under my Build Settings - but it makes my bundle identifier under the general "org.sd54.-4Miles"

Any idea why this is?  It's causing me to not be able to archive the app and get it distributed because the AppID doesn't match the bundle ID in xcode.

I want it to read: org.sd54.54Miles - but currently I cannot get it to stop reading org.sd54.-4Miles

Cannot figure it out!

Comment: Check the settings in Xcode and manually override the bundle ID if it's not what you want.

Comment: Anyway to do that without manually overriding the settings?  I would prefer to not make things static that I don't have to, just in the event of future releases or other issues it might trickle down to.

Comment: Well check it first.  If it's incorrect in Xcode then it will be incorrect in the app bundle.

Comment: Well under Buildsettings->Packing it says Product Name: 54Miles ; However, under General->Bundle Identifier it says: 'org.myorg.-4Miles', it's correct in product name, but for some reason it's removing the leading number and replacing it with '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just leaving the bundle ID as it was since apparently Apple has a problem leading with digits in the bundle identifier.

So I just created a new App ID in the developer site to match it.  I have since been able to deploy it without issue.

Comment: You mean you created App Id as "org.sd54.-4Miles" in developer site to match Xcode including "-" ?